# TinyMCE, allow data attribute in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: tinymce, prestashop-1.6

I have problem with my Prestashop 1.6  tinymce. It's remove my data attributes from html. I was trying to add  extended_valid_elements and

```
valid_elements : '@[id|class|title|style|data-options|data*]'
```

but nothing help. Change my classes/Validate.php to

```
public static function isCleanHtml($html, $allow_iframe = false)
{

    return true;
}
```

this is my html

```
public static function isCleanHtml($html, $allow_iframe = false)
{

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the HTMLPurifier Library PS is using in your backoffice under `Preferences > General > Use HTMLPurifier Library`. This should allow you to use data attributes in cms pages.

I am actually unsure how much of a security issue this is, especially if you are the only one editing CMS pages and your shop is otherwise reasonably secured.

Depending on what you are actually trying to achieve by using data attributes in the PS CMS, it is probably better advice to create a module and hook it to the cms pages.

**edit** you also probably don't want to change any of the functions in the `Validate` class, or any other, that could have an impact on many more things in such a complicated platform as Prestashop. If you really feel you need to: use [overrides](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors).

Comment: I needed to put data attributes in the code for CMS page.  I disabled HTML purifier as suggested, then added the code , saved.  And once the page was saved, I enabled HTML purifier again.  Thanks to the above tip.